# Paypal integration throws an error - Undefined index: log.FileName

Tags: laravel, paypal-rest-sdk

I am integrating a paypal in my website. I referred this link -
[link](https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-54)

But this gives me an error -

```
Undefined index: log.FileName
…\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Log\PayPalLogger.php66
```

I don't know why it is not working still it's a same code of above link.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. As you can see, the sdk is not able to create a log file at the given location. Can you please provide write permissions to make that happen ? That should let your see the right error message

Comment: Yes, I have given a permission. I just cross verified.